# Zend_Mail bug emailing with $mail->setReplyTo

Tags: php, zend-mail

Why does setReplyTo($reply_to_mail) send email to $reply_to_mail? Shouldn't it just add email adress to reply-to field in the email message?

Currenyly if sending mail from website form and filling reply-to field, message sends to reply-to email and to our admin email.

Why does it duplicates email? Should send only to our admin email.

```
class Helper_Mail extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function direct($email,$from,$message,$title,$replyto='')
    {
        $this->sendmail($email,$from,$message,$title,$replyto);
    }

    private function sendMail($email,$from,$message,$title,$replyto)
    {
        /* Configuring SMTP settings */
        $config = array(
            'auth' => 'login',
            'ssl' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'adminmail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => 587);

        $smtpHost = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com',$config);
        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($smtpHost);

        $mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
        $mail->setBodyHtml($message);
        $mail->setFrom('adminmail@gmail.com', $from);
        $mail->addTo($email);
        $mail->setSubject($title);

        if(!empty($replyto))
        {
            $mail->setReplyTo($replyto);
        }

        try
        {
            $mail->send();
        }
        catch(Zend_Mail_Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i remove setReplyTo from script, message sends fine, but without reply-to email in the message head.

Comment: Maybe try to use addHeader()? Could someone please show example with addHeader()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, fixed in new versions. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Zend_Mail::setReplyTo() if you are using a version of Zend > 1.8

If not (<= 1.8) you should use Zend_Mail::addHeader('Reply-To', 'replymail@example.com')